# Views are not updated in ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework

As I am new to ionic - I have question about app interface refreshing.
I have www folder in my ionic app. When i change content of HTML files inside this folder I am expecting that iOS and Android apps would be also changed. But this is not happening.

Maybe i need to disable cache somehow? If so - how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to build project so that contents from outer www folder will be copied to inner platform folder's www folder.

To build hit following command.

- `ionic build` - this will build all platforms
- `ionic build android` - this will build android platform only. Similarly for ios.
- `ionic serve lab` will reflect live changes. [Other options](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/test.html)

[Reference](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html)

Regards.

Comment: so i should rebuild it from console each time i make changes?

Comment: Check my updated answer. You will not have to build everytime.

Answer (score 1):

> Set cache false in your routing state like

```
$stateProvider.state('loginState', {
 cache: false,
 url : '/url',
 templateUrl : 'template.html'
})
```

And if you are looking for live app view change use

> LiveReload

Instantly update your apps with code changes, even when running directly on your device.

```
 $ ionic run --livereload
```

Comment: Sorry, what file should i change for this?

Comment: under /www/js/app.js